# showing full email template saved in db to a div jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have been saving email templates to `PostgreSQL`, they are like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoyzVR, But I am unable to show this html to a div with an id of `dat`.

```
    template = $($.parseXML(data)).children('html') #its from an already answered question
    # console.log template
    # $("#dat").innerHTML(template.data)
    console.log template
    document.getElementById('dat').innerHTML=template
    # page.innerHTML(template)
```

I have tried the above things, also prevent using innerHTML and just use `.add`, `.append`, `.html` for div with an id `dat`but either it's coming as an object if I do this

```
template = $($.parseHTML(data)).html()
```

Is there any possibility to show this in a div?

UPDATE:
Template variable after `$.parseHTML` looks like this

[image]

Comment: do you have the whole code in JSFiddle?

Comment: Do your `template` variable has required HTML?

Comment: I have updated the template value you can see that now